# If the JavaScript object has same key with different value, Get only the last key value of the duplicate keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am using java script array objects to store the data fetched from a database.
Here I have stored the value with same keys.
If the Javascript objects has same key but with different values,I need to get the last key and value of the duplicates

```
          var input = [ { month: 'Jan', value: 3 },
              { month: 'Jan', value: 3.5 },
              { month: 'Feb', value: 2.1 },
              { month: 'Mar', value: 6 },
              { month: 'Apr', value: 4.3 },
              { month: 'May', value: 5.5 },
              { month: 'Jun', value: 7 },
              { month: 'Jun', value: 9 },
              { month: 'Jul', value: 7 },
              { month: 'Jul', value: 9 },
              { month: 'Jul', value: 7 },
              { month: 'Aug', value: 9 },
              { month: 'Sep', value: 9 },
              { month: 'Sep', value: 9 },
              { month: 'Oct', value: 8 },
              { month: 'Oct', value: 5 },
              { month: 'Oct', value: 3 },
              { month: 'Nov', value: 12 },
              { month: 'Nov', value: 19.5 } ];

            var result = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                var data = input[i];
                var found=false;
                for(var j=0; j<result.length; j++) {
                    if(result[j].month === data.month) {
                        found=true;
                        result[j].value += data.value;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!found) {
                    result.push(data);
                }
            }

            //The result array is your desired result
            console.log(result);
```

In the above code It will add the  values of the same key and display the result.
But I need to get the last key and value of the duplicate keys.
Eg:
 It has 
    month:jan ,value:3 and
    month:jan , value:3.5 .
I need to get only last key value.
(i.e) month :jan ,value:3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When iterating over the array, assign each object to an object whose key is the month. This way, if a later item has the same month as an earlier one, the later item will overwrite the earlier one on the object.

```js
var input = [ { month: 'Jan', value: 3 },
  { month: 'Jan', value: 3.5 },
  { month: 'Feb', value: 2.1 },
  { month: 'Mar', value: 6 },
  { month: 'Apr', value: 4.3 },
  { month: 'May', value: 5.5 },
  { month: 'Jun', value: 7 },
  { month: 'Jun', value: 9 },
  { month: 'Jul', value: 7 },
  { month: 'Jul', value: 9 },
  { month: 'Jul', value: 7 },
  { month: 'Aug', value: 9 },
  { month: 'Sep', value: 9 },
  { month: 'Sep', value: 9 },
  { month: 'Oct', value: 8 },
  { month: 'Oct', value: 5 },
  { month: 'Oct', value: 3 },
  { month: 'Nov', value: 12 },
  { month: 'Nov', value: 19.5 }
];
const obj = {};
for (const item of input) {
  obj[item.month] = item;
}
const output = Object.values(obj);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance.Thanks for your answer.This is what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reduce as follows if the months' order is sequential:

```js
const input = [{ month: 'Jan', value: 3 }, { month: 'Jan', value: 3.5 }, { month: 'Feb', value: 2.1 }, { month: 'Mar', value: 6 }, { month: 'Apr', value: 4.3 }, { month: 'May', value: 5.5 }, { month: 'Jun', value: 7 }, { month: 'Jun', value: 9 }, { month: 'Jul', value: 7 }, { month: 'Jul', value: 9 }, { month: 'Jul', value: 7 }, { month: 'Aug', value: 9 }, { month: 'Sep', value: 9 }, { month: 'Sep', value: 9 }, { month: 'Oct', value: 8 }, { month: 'Oct', value: 5 }, { month: 'Oct', value: 3 }, { month: 'Nov', value: 12 }, { month: 'Nov', value: 19.5 }];

const result = [];

input.reduce((a, v, i) => {
  const eleIdx = a.findIndex(e => e.month === v.month);
  if (eleIdx > -1 && input[i - 1].month === v.month) {
    a[eleIdx].value = v.value;
  } else {
    a.push(v);
  }
  return a;
}, result);


console.log(result);
```